# Certificate pinning between android and mvc api server

Tags: certificate, pinning

Can you please help me to implement certificate pinning between android app and MVC web APIs.

Please help me with example code if possible

Your help is most valuable to me

Thanks & Regards
Ragesh MK

Answer (score 0):

If your API are running under https, you should only add certificate pinning to the android app.

A good starting point is this [owasp guide](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning#Android).